# Split *.dat file with fixed width with each width known

Tags: python, pandas, split

I have a *.dat file. I know the locations I want to split the file at. They are

```
[5,5,10,10,10,10,10,5,5,10]
```

However, the pandas read_fwf takes the values in the format:

```
[(0, 5), (5, 10), (10, 20), (20, 30), (30, 40), (40, 50), (50, 60), (60, 65), (65, 70), (70, 80)]
```

How do I convert the above values to the values below?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `colspecs` parameter of `read_fwf` uses half-open intervals, so actually it expects

```
[(0, 5), (5, 10), (10, 20), …]
```

If you cumulatively add the widths, you get your start (and end) indices:

```
widths = [5,5,10,10,10,10,10,5,5,10]
borders = np.cumsum([0] + widths)
>>> array([ 0,  5, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 65, 70, 80])
```

And then use `zip` on the lower and upper ends:

```
list(zip(borders[:-1], borders[1:]))
>>> [(0, 5), (5, 10), (10, 20), (20, 30), (30, 40), (40, 50), (50, 60), (60, 65), (65, 70), (70, 80)]
```

Answer (score 4):

I would use numpy cumsum:

```
In [11]: c = np.cumsum([5,5,10,10,10,10,10,5,5,10])

In [12]: s = np.insert(c + 1, 0, 0)

In [13]: list(zip(s, c))
Out[13]:
[(0, 5),
 (6, 10),
 (11, 20),
 (21, 30),
 (31, 40),
 (41, 50),
 (51, 60),
 (61, 65),
 (66, 70),
 (71, 80)]
```

**Edit** :

```
s = np.insert(c, 0, 0)
list(zip(s,c))

[(0, 5),(5, 10),(10, 20), (20, 30), (30, 40), (40, 50), (50, 60), (60, 65), (65, 70), (70, 80)]
```

Comment: Sorry, my question was wrong, I didn't know that read_fwf read a different format. I have corrected the question.

Comment: @pnkjmndhl then instead of `c+1` use only `c`